# JDBC-ODBC Connecting to Excel

Tags: java, excel, jdbc, odbc

I'm trying to access a Microsoft Excel file via Java by using the sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver. However, I keep getting : "java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified".

```
try
{
 Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
 Connection c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls)};DBQ="+ fileName + ";DriverID=22;READONLY=false;");
 c.close();
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(parent, ex.toString());
}
```

Cheers!

Comment: The ODBC DLL is not shipped with the 64-bit JDK, so if you're using a 64-bit OS you're out of luck.

Comment: Its been awhile, I remember you need to create a datasource for ODBC connection, did you try that?

Comment: Not with the DNS-less URL that he posted; that step isn't necessary.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is WAYYYYYY late but, just in case anyone else ever wanders around here:

I'm pretty sure you need the whole filepath up to and including the file you want to connect to.
Something like this:

```
Class.forName($Driver"URL").newInstance();
CONNECTION = DriverManager.getConnection( "jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls)};DBQ=C:/Users/Pat/Documents/test.xls");
```